# SSRS - Place grouped data on the same row

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, rows, reporting

I'm facing this `SSRS` issue that I can't seem to get working properly.
I got employees that work on particular projects on specific dates. I want the dates as columns and the projects per date on 1 row.

What I have now:
[image]

What I want to have:
[image]

Can anyone help me to get there?

Thanks!

Comment: will [this article](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/grouping-in-ssrs-matrix-reports/) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Check the row group properties. You only need s single row group and that should only group by employee. My guess is that you group is grouping on more than just employee or you have more than one group.

Your row group should **not** be grouping by date, only the column group should group by date.